# Spring JPA repository find all which does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

and the Entity looks like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

I want to have a method which checks if all "persons" exist in database table by id, this what I have so far:

```
void checkIfAllPersonsExist(List<Long> personIds) {
    var persons = personRepository.findAllById(personIds);
    if (personIds.size() != persons.size()) {
        personIds.removeAll(persons.stream().map(Persons::getId).collect(toList()));
        throw new NotFoundException("Persons with id's [id:%s] does not exist", personIds);
    }
}
```

I wonder if Spring JPA Repository can provide anything more elegant? Like specific named query which returns id's which does not exist?

Comment: Why in `JpaRepository<Person, String> {}` Id is as `String` not `Long`?

Comment: @lczapski that's just a typo, I have edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just know that there are some ids that not exist you can count them

```java
@Query("select COUNT(p.id) from Person p where p.id in :ids")
Long countIds(List<Long> ids);
```

Or equivalent [based on](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

```java
long countByIdIn(Collection<Long> ids);
```

Or return list of ids that exists

```java
@Query("select p.id from Person p where p.id in :ids")
List<Long> getExistenIds(List<Long> ids);
```

And then filter out what you need.

```java
personIds.removeAll(personRepository.getExistenIds(personIds));
if (!personIds.isEmpty()) {
    throw new NotFoundException("Persons with id's [id:%s] does not exist", personIds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your repository should extend `JpaRepository<Person, Long>` instead of `JpaRepository<Person, String >`, because your entity's id type is `Long`.

`In` and `NotIn` keywords can help you to achive your goal. Please check them out in this document: [Query Creation - Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

I modified your code a little bit and it works for me.

Repository class:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByIdIn(Collection<Long> ids);
}
```

And sample snippet:

```
@Component
public class Bootstrap implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        savePersons();

        testFindMethod();
    }

    private void savePersons() {
        Person person1 = Person.builder().id(1L).name("Name 1").build();
        Person person2 = Person.builder().id(2L).name("Name 2").build();
        Person person3 = Person.builder().id(3L).name("Name 3").build();
        Person person4 = Person.builder().id(4L).name("Name 4").build();

        repository.save(person1);
        repository.save(person2);
        repository.save(person3);
        repository.save(person4);
    }

    private void testFindMethod() {
        List<Long> toFind = new ArrayList<>();
        toFind.add(1L);
        toFind.add(2L);
        toFind.add(3L);
        checkIfAllPersonsExist(toFind);

        toFind.add(7L);
        checkIfAllPersonsExist(toFind);
    }

    void checkIfAllPersonsExist(List<Long> personIds) {
        List<Person> persons = repository.findByIdIn(personIds);
        if (personIds.size() != persons.size()) {
            System.out.println("Sizes are different");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sizes are same!");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is console output:

```
Sizes are same!
Sizes are different
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This nice and all, but that's not what I asked for. You just check if all id's exist, I want to know which does not. Also I want to return only Id's not whole entities. But thanks for your input, great job.

Comment: I can clearly read this in your question: `I want to have a method which checks if all "persons" exist in database table by id`

Answer (score 0):

With this JPA repository method you can get the elements which ids doesn't exists:

```
List<Person> findByIdNotIn(List<Long> personIds);
```

If you want to remove them like in your example, you can use this one:

```
List<Person> deleteByIdNotIn(List<Long> personIds);
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This answer is wrong `findByIdNotIn` does not match the expected result. Why even upvote it?